# How to edit configuration parameters of php fmt (Sublime Text) for grading up PHP

Tags: php, sublimetext2

What I've been trying is to change `php_bin` parameter of phpfmt, Sublime.

**EDIT**

I'm using mac. When I opened Sublime, I was informed that I needed to upgrade php from 5.5. to higher. Following [the documentation of phpfmt](https://github.com/phpfmt/sublime-phpfmt), I changed the file after I upgraded it. The file looks like this,

```
{
"version": 4,
"php_bin":"/usr/local/etc/php/7.0",
// "format_on_save":true,
"option": "value"
}
```

Still, I'm seeing a warning message.

> Warning.
>       PHP 5.6 or newer is required.
>       Please, upgrade your local PHP installation.

I deleted the line `"version": 4,`, but nothing changed.

To my shame, I'm clueless as to how to solve this problem.

I'd appreciate if you could tell me anything I'm doing wrong, or any other advice as to how to stop this warning message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an newer version of PHP.

First, confirm you actually have it.

```
$ php -v
PHP 7.0.2 (cli) (built: Jan  7 2016 10:40:26) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
```

Once you do it, confirm its whole path:

```
$ which php
/usr/local/bin/php
```

Add `/usr/local/bin/php` to `php_bin` in the configuration file.

Keep in mind, that sometimes PHP installers place the new PHP in a different address. If you are in a MacOS X and using homebrew, it is likely to be placed under `/usr/local/Cellar/php70/7.0.x/bin/php`

Answer (score 0):

In Mac OS X Terminal.app check the location of php:

```
whereis php
```

This may return something like this:

> /usr/bin/php

Then make a link to the location that Sublime text is checking:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/php /usr/local/etc/php
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Unfortunately, however, this didn't solve the problem.